# How to combine two columns on the same table using Hive

Tags: sql, hive, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

Right now I have:

| Scorecard | team1 | team2 | Winner | Margin | Ground | Match Date | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ODI # 1 | Australia | England | Australia | 5 wickets | Melbourne | 5-Jan-71 | 1971 |
| ODI # 2 | England | Australia | England | 6 wickets | Manchester | 24-Aug-72 | 1972 |
| ODI # 3 | England | Australia | Australia | 5 wickets | Lord's | 26-Aug-72 | 1972 |
| ODI # 4 | England | Australia | England | 2 wickets | Birmingham | 28-Aug-72 | 1972 |
| ODI # 5 | New Zealand | Pakistan | New Zealand | 22 runs | Christchurch | 11-Feb-73 | 1973 |

And what I want to is combine team1 and team2 and then get distant list

Example based on what I have above:

| teams |
| --- |
| Australia |
| England |
| New Zealand |
| Pakistan |

I am using Cloudera Hive- I was trying to get a union to work.

I also tried:

```
SELECT concat_ws('^',(SPLIT('${team1,team2}',',')));
```

However, the output is just giving me:
${team1^team2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiet way would be to use `union`:

```
select team1 as teams from tablename
union distinct
select team2 from tablename
```

Here is another ways using sub query :

```
Select distinct teams from (
select team1 as teams from tablename
union
select team2 from tablename 
) t
```

Comment: So I had to add some things to make it work `select distinct team1 as teams from tablename union all select distinct team2 as teams from tablename;` Now, my follow up question how be how to get the new teams list to be distinct? Its not save within the original table.

Comment: @Jackis. Hmm , see updated answer , see if that works